# Fire function only if action lasts more than 500ms

Tags: jquery

So, I'm writing a function to work around a browser bug, I won't go into the specifics, because as you know with bugs, even describing them succinctly can be a pain.

Anyway, what I have is a jquery function that fires a click when the mouse enters a specific area, the problem I'm having is I want it to fire ONLY if the mouse is in there for more than half a second.

Now I tried to settimeout, but all that does is delay the firing, as soon as you mouse over, the function carries on it's merry way.
So, how would I only fire the .click function only if .left is hovered for more than 500ms?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.left').mouseenter(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.latest').click();
        }, 500);
    });

    $('.left-3').mouseenter(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.popular').click();
        }, 500);
    });

    $('.left-5').mouseenter(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('.favsurl').click();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `setTimeout()` on mouseenter, and `clearTimeout()` on mouseleave. That way if the mouse is moved out before the time is up the timeout is cancelled and your function doesn't get called.

```
    var timerID;

    $('.left').mouseenter(function() { 
        timerID = setTimeout(function () {
            $('.latest').click();
        }, 500); 
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MWDcg/

Comment: Would that stop the click function from actually firing though? Wouldn't that just mean it fired as soon as the mouse left the area?

Comment: No. The `clearTimeout` removes the callback function that was set entirely. It never gets called, unless 500ms have passed.

Comment: Ah, that's perfect, thanks nnnnnn. Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: P.S. There's no harm in calling `clearTimeout()` even _after_ the time is up and your function has already been called. If you call `clearTimeout()` and pass an id that doesn't reference an "active" timeout nothing happens (no error). That's why there are no `if` statements or anything in the code I provided.